# VS Code(python): How to making model import work properly(i.e. resolve ModuleNotFoundError) without code modification

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a script inside a project which can be simplified to the following structure.In vs code, imports are not working properly, my question is how can I make this work.

```
.
├── scripts
│   └── foo.py
└── src
    ├── mod1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── mod1
    │       └── hoge.py
    └── mod2
        ├── __init__.py
        └── mod2
            └── bar.py
```

In file ./scripts/foo.py, I try to import from mod1.hoge and mod2.bar by the following code:

```py
import mod1.hoge as hoge
import mod2.bar as bar

if __name__=="__main__":
    hoge.g(2)==bar.f(2,2)
```

Here, hoge.g is defined in ./src/mod1/mod1/hoge/py which is as follows:

```py
import mod2.bar as bar

def g(a):
    return bar.f(a,a)
```

It imports from mod2.bar which can be some random function.

When I try to run foo.py it says

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod1'
```

So I added a launch.json in which I wrote:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}/src/mod1"}
        }
    ]
}
```

However this didn't work at all, so I changed the **env** to below:

```
"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}/src/mod1"}
```

this time, it seems that mod1 is correctly imported from foo.py, but when hoge.py tries to import bar.py it failed again with the below error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod2'
```

with below traceback:

```
File "/pj1/src/mod1/mod1/hoge.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mod2.bar as bar
File "/pj1/scripts/foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mod1.hoge as hoge
```

So my question is basically How to make this work.
In more detail:

- can I assign multiple path to PYTHONPATH in lauch.json?

  ```
  "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}/src/mod1;${workspaceRoot}/src/mod2"}
  ```

  I have tried the above but it did work.
- If multiple path can be assigned, is it possible to use reg-ex?
- is there any better way to handle this?

Comment: "is there any better way to handle this?" :
Use `sys.path` to fix path imports. `sys.path.append("/path/to/src/mod1")`. Now you can use `from mod1.hoge import *`

Comment: @DeGo thanks for the suggestion, it does work. however, I don't really want to touch the code, I'd rather modify vs code setting. Just want to emphasise the above example is a simplified version of a huge project. With your approach, to run a script, I'll need to add sys.path.append to thousands of files and bear the risk of committing unwanted code to the codebase, which I'm not sure is something that I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just worked out a solution, if there are more elegant ways please let me know.

What I did was as below, basically change the "**;**" to "**:**" . Then it works.

```
- "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}/src/mod1;${workspaceRoot}/src/mod2"} 
+ "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}/src/mod1:${workspaceRoot}/src/mod2"}
```

Furthermore, I wonder if there is a more generic way to do so. So, I created an env variable in my .bashrc to get all paths of sub dirs of src, and the final launch.json is as follows

```
 {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": ${env:SRCSUBDIRS}}
        }
    ]
}
```

In .bashrc:

```
SUBDIRARRY=(~/PATH/TO/src/*/)
export SRCSUBDIRS=$(IFS=:; echo "${SUBDIRARRY[*]}")
```

There must be better solutions but the above works for me now, if anyone knows any better solution please let me know! Thanks